# form.Timer interval drift

Tags: forms, timer, intervals, drift

I have a timer where the on_time event interval increase over time. It should be 100ms and it drif on one hour to more than 200ms. See the picture.
[out put from the timer at start and 1 hour later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrgRz.png)
On top is the correct timer, on bottom is the timer after one hour work.
My question is what can be the reason and how to proceed to have a better timer.

Thanks in advance

I try a system timer, but it is dificult to manage all the code related to the form.